# When checkbox is checked populate a list of the items in a div jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox

I have 2 seperate divs with check boxes in, when I click on the check boxes from one div I want to be able to get all the items checked within that one div and then populate a div comma seperated into another div, and same for the other div.

I kind of have it working but going into a textbox and I want to change this but not sure how, its pretty much done, just needs tweeking. Here is a link to what I have got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/162/

Comment: The only problem is the text within the html has disappeared http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/165/ how can I get the headings within the div then populate the list below the headings? Also * How can I get a space after each comma??

Answer (score 0):

Change the tags from `textarea`s to `div`s and set the content with `.text()` instead of `.val()`. see http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/163/

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem? Your code worked totally fine... I noticed all your checkboxes have the same value, that's why it always print `Comfort Access`, but if you set the correct values it will be ok.

The implicit Array to String conversion is producing the exact output you want, but if you want something more explicit, use `allVals.join(',')`.

Comment: The only problem is the text within the html has disappeared jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/165 how can I get the headings within the div then populate the list below the headings? Also * How can I get a space after each comma??

Comment: Dunno about the headings, but to get a space after each comma just use `allVals.join(', ')`.